# vue-tsc errors don't show files or line numbers

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite, tsc

I am not sure if this is a problem with typescript 5.1.6, vite 4.3.8, or VSCode 1.79.2, vue-tsc 1.6.4 (or something else). I am not seeing filenames or line numbers in the terminal output after running `vue-tsc && vite build`.

So, for example:

```
yarn workspace v1.22.19
yarn run v1.22.19
$ vue-tsc && vite build

error TS7006: Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.

error TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.

error TS7006: Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'slots'.

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'slots'.

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'slots'.

error TS2304: Cannot find name 'slots'.

Found 7 errors.
```

Edit:
Also, I am using [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) (yarn 1.22.19) to have multiple workspaces in a single monorepo, and am using typescript [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to allow projects in one workspace to reference projects in another.